# ASP.NET API endpoint not being triggered with a particular naming convention

Tags: asp.net, routes, blazor

I used to be able to trigger a GET endpoint in my controller route named

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

but for some reason this has stopped working. Now, it only works if I rename the route to something completely different e.g.

```
[Route("test/[controller]")]
[Route("[controller]")]
```

**What could be causing this behaviour?**

For some context, here's something else I noticed: If I debug with "http" selected, I can trigger the endpoint using "api/todos" (or any other name for the endpoint). However, if I debug with "https", I can trigger using any other name but "api/todos". Note: I don't use [Authorize] on my controller.

Razor page code:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "api/todos");

        var response = await Http.SendAsync(request);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

"TodosController" code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodosController : ControllerBase
{
     TodoDataAccess objTodo = new TodoDataAccess();

     [HttpGet]
     public string Get()
     {
        return "test;
     }

}
```

Comment: Well, something was changed or at least updated on your end. Not much chance of anybody spotting it here. Set up a [mre] (in a new project).

Comment: Re the update: did you verify that this produces the error in a new project?

Comment: Yes - I can't reproduce it in a new project. Still investigating what could have changed in the configuration of the existing project to cause this. I've been trying to setup an authentication middleware for JWT but don't see how/where that could impact on this naming issue.